# Print header on first page only with media style

Tags: html, css

I created a

```
<style media="print"> #header{ display: none; } </style>
```

to hide the header when user selects Browser's 'Print' Command. This will hide the header on all pages. I need to Display Header on first page but hide on all the others. Can any one advice how can this be done with the 'Media' Style?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use javascript for that, you can try something like

```
var urlPath= window.location.pathname;
if (urlPath.length > 1)
    document.getElementById("header").style.display="none";
```

or with jquery

```
$("#header").hide();
```

Comment: I Do need to see the header on the first page but hide on the rest. Will this do the trick or just hide the header on ALL pages?

Comment: it should show the header only at home page and hide it in the rest of the pages or more accurate it would hide the header if there is a path after the domain name

Comment: Just to be clear, will this work on the Print Preview Pages?

Comment: What do you mean print preview?

Comment: Well, as I stated in my initial post, The header needs to hidden on all but first page when user selects the Browser's 'Print' command. Please revisit my initial post.